# Problems with labels in CollectionView header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel

I was trying to insert labels into headers, but when I scroll the collectionView, another label is add on view. How I can stop this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaarJ.png)

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath)
    header.backgroundColor = .white
    let label = UILabel(frame: header.bounds)
    label.text = colorsArray[indexPath.section]
    header.addSubview(label)
    return header
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass the header and add the label there. So you will not every time add a label to the header.

To remove all labels and add it again is very bad practice and a big overhead.

Comment: I really need to use a header, so I can't do that.

Comment: But you can subclass the header with UICollectionReusableView

Comment: Oh, sorry, the code ' cell.label.text = "something" ' confused me.
You are right, it works very well. Thanks